# Android application crashes due to low memory

Tags: android

My application is basically a image viewer. It is opened from both camera and as a separate application.

I open the image viewer to view and edit the picture. Each edit operation is implemented using thread. If my application closes due to pressing the home button, the next time I open it with camera. It throws anr.

This doesn't always happen. Only when large edit operations or edit operations on large image files are done.

I get out of memory error, sometimes timeout.

I guess it s because the thread doesn't complete the edit operation when home is clicked. and it s still running on the background. so when i open it s unable to process it.

m I right?

If so what is the way to stop a thread before the completion/

Can u pls help me out?

Comment: can you please tell what mistake you were doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like memory leak. Check for memory leaks in your code

Answer (score 0):

Might look at a thread I opened on out of memory issue on large images. Several suggestions in there on what might help you: 
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)

Comment: I tried out recycle() and then gc... it worked out. It solved the out of memory issue... Thank you... :):)

Answer (score 0):

Threads are not garbage collected until they are stopped or their process is killed (which usually takes a while, even after all activities are closed). That also means that any objects referenced by those threads aren't garbage collected either.

There are multiple ways to shut down a thread, depending on what exactly it is doing. Best way is to check for a variable at certain points during it's execution, and exit the `run`-Method when that variable is set. Best place for that is usually within the condition of a `while`-loop. You can than set that variable from the outside, and the thread will shut down the next time it checks for it. Remember to mark that variable as `volatile`. Example:

```
private volatile boolean mStopped = false;

public void run() {
   while(!mStopped) {
      // do something
      if(mStopped)
          return;
      // do something more
   }
}
```

If a thread is waiting, you'll have to interrupt it. See the `interrupt`-Method of the `Thread`-Class for that.